# Чего вам не хватает в PHP?

Tags: php, предложения

Такой вот маленький опрос.

**Чего вам не хватает в PHP?**

Какие функции приходится писать постоянно, что хочется чтобы было, а его нет, либо в плохом исполнении?

Comment: вы, надо полагать, их дадите?

Answer (score 2):

Большинство того, что отсутствует в чистом php присутствует во фреймворках в том или ином виде. По крайней мере, это касается постоянно используемых функций.
Те немногие вещи, которые все же остаются(или присутствуют не везде) относятся скорее к проблеме русификации, как то расширенная функция для множественного числа, более удобная функция для гоняния даты, функции по работе с определенными форматами файлов.

Это тоже все ищется, но уже не так быстро.